# MSTSC.exe for Windows CE

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-ce

I am using an old pc with Windows CE 4.2 Pro installed and I want to connect it in a windows 2003 server. However I need a Remote Desktop Connection to do so (duh) which did not come with this windows (or it was removed, not really sure). I have tried to install a regular mstsc.exe or even ones for mobile phones, but when I try to run it, it gives me a "This is not a Windows CE application" error.

Any ideas, guys?

Thanks

Comment: For those that are in the same situation as I am, I've found this http://code.google.com/p/rdesktop-ce/downloads/list I didnt try it myself yet, will post back with results

Comment: The mstsc.exe on mobile phones would be an ARM (or possibly a MIPS or Super-H) executable and that's why it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Mobile Powertoys.

The Power Toys include:

```
    Emulator ActiveSync Connection Tool - Allows Activesync to connect to your Emulator session from Visual Studio .NET 2003.

    ActiveSync Remote Display - Display Pocket PC applications on your desktop or laptop without needing any device side configuration.

    CECopy - Command line tool for copying files to the device currently connected to desktop ActiveSync.

    Convert PPC DAT to SP XML - Command line tool for generating Smartphone CABWizSP XML docs from existing Pocket PC CAB files.

    Hopper - User input stress simulator.

    JShell - UI version of the Platform Builder Target Control Window.

    PPC Command Shell - Command shell for the Pocket PC 2003 device.

    RAPI Debug - Displays detailed information about currently running processes.

    RAPI Start - Command line tool to remotely start an application on your Pocket PC from your desktop.

    TypeIt - Send characters/strings to the Smartphone 2003 Emulator via ActiveSync.
```

Supported Operating System

```
Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP

Windows Mobile 2003 based Pocket PCs

Windows Mobile 2003 based Smartphones

Windows Mobile 2002 based Pocket PCs

Windows Mobile 2002 based Smartphones
```

Not all tools are supported on all listed platforms.

There are two packages to download. The Emulator Activesync Connection Tool comes as one package. The remaining tools come in a second package.

```
Emulator Activesync Connection Tool

    Start Visual Studio .NET 2003.

    Click "Connect Emulator with ActiveSync" on the Tools menu.

    From the "Connect Emulator with ActiveSync" dialog, select an Emulator image from
    the dropdown list.

    Ensure the selected emulator is not running yet.

    Click the Connect button. The emulator will be started and an ActiveSync
    connection will be established with it.

    Once the connection is ready, it is OK to close the tool by clicking Exit
    from the menu.


Remaining Power Toys
All the other Power Toys are installed by the second installation package. A shortcut called Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys is created on the Start Menu which will allow you to access the Power Toys. The readme file for each toy explains how the Power Toy is used.
```

**References**

- [Download Windows CE Developer Power Toys](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10601)